# Is it safe to store access token in next-auth session?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

What I want is to access the customer details in the `client side` in `next.js` and I need to pass the `customer access token` to the backend API. Using `next-auth`, I was able to store the access token to the session but is it safe or is it better to use the `next.js api route` and use `getToken` function? I'm still a beginner in frontend security, I don't know if I'm just being a paranoid but I can't find a topic/post that states it is completely safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So by default the session strategy is set to `jwt`, which means your session is encoded / signed and safe to store sensitive info in.

However, NextAuth.js can be used to automatically put that accessToken you get from your OAuth provider in the JWT token via the `jwt` callback. Therefore you can pull it out anywhere with the `getToken()` method you mentioned and authenticate against Google APIs for further use (get drive contents, contacts, etc, etc, etc).

Check out this example for how to do that in the `jwt` callback: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-refresh-token-example/blob/57f84dbc50f30233d4ee389c7239212858ecae14/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.js#L67

Comment: unfortunately getToken() doesn't work from a server component, because there's no access to the request :-(

Comment: Yeah I have to clarify now, this was written for Next.js 12 specifically. Before server components and the like.

Comment: For the latest next js and next-auth it is possible to get token on server:

const getToken = async () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const sessionToken = cookieStore.get('authjs.session-token');
  console.log('sessionToken', sessionToken)

  return decoded;
}